# The fundamental differences between Unix and Windows

Tags: windows, unix, architecture, operating-system

Without getting too technical (because I am not a professional) I would really like to know what the fundamental differences are between Unix based operating-systems and MS Windows. 
I realize that this is a very broad question, so I will try to be more specific.

1. Why is it that Unix based OS:s does not seem to have a problem with fragmentation and/or gradual decline in speed, while Windows does. I know it's a question of architecture, but how is it achived in broad terms, and why would Windows be any different.
2. I heard somewhere that Windows are more prone to get viruses not only because of their market share, but because of the OS's structure. (something about compatibility and adding DLL files all the time) I wonder how that come, and if you could theoreticly do anything about it at this point.

Comment: Have you tried researching this on your own? I would do it for you, but I charge by the hour...

Comment: Oh thank you so much my friend, but the research goes a little slow when I don't really know what to search for, I just have an interest, I'm not an expert. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your question is the fact that there are many unix variants. One of the major differences is how Windows and Unix treat a process, I will stick to your questions:

1) The traditional Unix file system is incapable of ensuring data within a file is contiguous. Files are represented as data segments linked as lists. There is no way to defragment a unix file system.

Many files systems (like NTFS) perform better when the file is contiguous on disk. They use variable length file "extents" that are contiguous areas on disk. A file can have one or more extents. A file with one extent is defragmented.

Generally, the performance of hard file systems like NTFS is better than that of traditional unix file system. The inability to create contiguous files is the reason Unix systems require a swap partition and why databases on Unix tend to implement their own file system within a partition.

2. In ye old days, shared libraries had to be installed by the operating system. The system manager controlled what version of a shared library was run. Windoze locates DLLs through the path. There is no central control over what DLL is used.

Unix users tend to run without any privileges. Windows kinda sorta reigns in the user but he can do anything he wants really. That makes it easier for vira to attack.